# FPGA Synchronized Digit Counter goes Asynchronous!

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, counter

I'm trying to implement one digit counter from 0 to 9 using an FPGA board. The digit is incremented when the signal "pulse" is set.
The "pulse" signal is set every fixed number N of clock cycles. The clock frequency is 5 MHz. 
However the counter jumps inconsistently depending on the "pulse" period. For example when it's set to 1000000, the 
counter works fine and the digit is incremented every 1/5 of a second. When the period is different, it does not behave as expected.
Even if the period is set longer, every 5000000 clock cycles, it jumps from 0 to 1 to 0..., the increment is 10!

Here's the VHDL code that increments the counter based on the pulse.

```
process(clk, reset)
begin
    if (reset = '1') then
        digit_reg <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then 
        digit_reg <= next_digit;
    end if;
end process;

process(pulse, digit_reg)
begin
    if (pulse = '1') then
        if (digit_reg >= 9) then 
            next_digit <= (others => '0');
        else 
            next_digit <= digit_reg + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean when you simulated it ?

Comment: Are you sure `pulse` is high for only one clock cycle? If not you need to make sure of that.

Comment: No, when synthesized.

Comment: First your next_digit is a latch. It gets set if pulse='1' but otherwise you haven not given it a value.
I have no idea where 'pulse' comes from. Is it generated of the same clock? I think we need to see more code from that.

Comment: I suppose "pulse" is high for one cycle, since it's synchronized with the same counter clock, and it does not change until the next clock edge rise.

Comment: Yes the "pulse" is generated from the same clock, and its value is set using another counter when it hits the fixed specific number, otherwise it's set to 0.

Comment: remove digit_reg from the sensitivity list and check.

Comment: I'm interested to know how removing digit_reg from the sensitivity list makes any difference, when it's supposed to be there as HDL requires?

Comment: First, don't remove `digit_reg` from sensitivity list. This answer is wrong! Second, create a proper next logic description for `next_digit`: Fix the VHDL description, so it doesn't generate a memory element (here it is a latch).  Hint: An else branch is missing. Third, why do you use such a complicated form the describe a simple counter with clock-enable? Your counter will not be mapped ideally to any existing FPGA hardware, because it has a asynchronous and synchronous reset. Firth, get rid of an asynchronous resets.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add an else branch to fix the broken combinatoric process description:

```
process(pulse, digit_reg)
begin
    if (pulse = '1') then
        if (digit_reg >= 9) then 
            next_digit <= (others => '0');
        else 
            next_digit <= digit_reg + 1;
        end if;
    else
        next_digit <= digit_reg;
    end if;
end process;
```

Your implementation will not fit good to any existing FPGA hardware because it uses an asynchronous **and** synchronous reset.

This is how to describe a **fully** synchronous counter modulo 9 with synchronous reset and clock enable (`pulse`):

```
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if ((reset = '1') or (digit_reg >= 9)) then
            digit_reg <= (others => '0');
        elsif (pulse = '1') then
            digit_reg <= digit_reg + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: You have completely misread the question. The OP is not trying to implement a mod-9 counter on "clk". He wants to count using the generated clock pulse.

Comment: Actually the counter rotates after 9 it restarts from 0, hence a mod-9 counter. Sorry for not clarifying this in the OP.

Comment: The other solution worked too! Thanks a lot! Though I still don't understand why need the else branch which for me should not affect the circuit. With/out else branch the next_digit is latched.

Comment: @joseph Seems like your question itself is misleading. If you are trying to implement a mod 9 counter on clk ( I thought pulse ) this is the correct solution indeed. Then why do you even describe like your functionality was met when it incremented every 1/5 seconds, at first place.

Comment: Maybe you did not notice that I check the value of the counter and if it's >= 9 then I reset to 0. :)

Comment: Both solutions worked! Why? I still have no idea!

Comment: I did. But your question is unclear on which clock you want a mod-9 counter. clk or pulse. if its on clk, whose period is 1/5000000, then why you talk about counting every 1/5 seconds ?

Comment: The main counter is mod-9 and to be synchronized with the "pulse". The pulse is set to 1 or 0 based on another counter that's synchronized with the main clock frequency 5 MHz.

Comment: @MITURAJ You still haven't understood how VHDL works and how VHDL or any other HDL is translated to hardware... My provided solution is not counting on `clk` is counting an every `pulse`. It is a fully synchronous counter. That the OP asked for a mod 9 counter can be seen in his code which resets the counter on `>= 9`.

Comment: @Joseph Explaining why might blow up that question... In short. A process drives one or more signals. A driving value is calculated based on all possible execution paths in a process. If an execution path does not describe a driving value, synthesis MUST implement a memory element. This is a flip-flop, if the process uses `rising_edge(...)` or `falling_edge(...)`, otherwise a latch. Your process was no pure combinatoric process, so it created a latch. A basic design rule is: **Don't describe latches, unless you know what you are doing.**

Comment: The unexpected behavior of an latch was now experienced by you. If you would have checked your synthesis reports, you would have seen such a design fault. So in conclusion: The else branch describes the last missing execution path, on what to do, when `pulse = '0'`. In that case you want to pass through a values. Actually, your second process wanted to describe a multiplexer, right?

Comment: Counter has to be incremented only on pulse's rising edge. Not on every clock's edge as long as pulse stays '1'. This is the requirement inferred from the question.

Comment: Pulse is a clock generated from clk, with period 5x10^6 cycles.

Comment: @MITURAJ Then he needs to a) clarify his question; b) present more code than just a counter; c) implement a edge detection circuits. You can NOT use `pulse` in a `rising_edge` function call; d) a signal named `pulse` implies an activity for only one clock cycle - otherwise the OP should rethink his signal name(s).

Comment: That's my point. This question is unclear.

Comment: @MITURAJ This is not a clock, it's a clock enable... And therefore my answer is correct.

Comment: OP never clarifies whether pulse is a generated clock of 5x10^6 clk cycles or a pulse of "clk period" that occurs every 1/5 seconds. I answered thinking the first way and you answered thinking the latter way

Comment: "You still haven't understood how VHDL works and how VHDL or any other HDL is translated to hardware " -- misleading question created your misconceptions.  I don't claim to be pro expert with 25+ industrial experience but knows enough to help people out here.

Comment: @Paebbels Your answer helped and I see why it works now. Thanks a lot.